# Concatenation of objects

Tags: java, object

I have a question concerning object concatenation in Java (Objects). Is it possible to concatenate the objects to send over a network as a single object?  What should I do? (I do not want to use arrays)

client code

```
public void run() { 

        Object Obj1 = getSousPop(ID); 

        Object Obj2 = problem; 

        Object OBJ [] = ??????????????? 

        try { 
            send(OBJ); 
        } catch (IOException ex) { 
            Logger.getLogger(Master.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
        } 
    }
```

Server code

```
Object receivedRequest = receive(); 
            System.out.println("j'ai reçu:" + receive()); 
            if(receivedRequest instanceof ServerData){ 
                Population pop = ((ServerData)receivedRequest).getPop(); 
                ISolvable problem = ((ServerData)receivedRequest).getSolve(); 
                for (int i = 0; i < pop.getSize(); i++) { 
                    problem.solve(pop.getElement(i)); 
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a question concerning object concatenation in java (Objects).
>   Is it possible to concatenate the objects to send over a network as a
>   single object?

My answer:  I don't think it's possible to concatenate two objects like that. It would be impossible for the compiler to determine what to do with the properties. For example, if we had two objects for a Person, each with a property like "Age", how should we concatenate it?   You need to define your own class of object with methods and properties, and you can then define a method which concatenates two objects of this class.

Comment: Sorry, I was responding to the original post which was in French. The original poster is new and I thought it might be helpful to leave the answer in French, as well as provide a translation in English.  If the questioner hasn't seen it by now, she may not know how or where to view my original post which included a response in her language and a translation into English.

Comment: Thank you so mutch for translation, i usually create with englich lol

Comment: I saw your answer, thank you so mutch but I think there is possibility to concatenate two object because i found instruction "instanceof" which allow to separate whole of objects and use each of objects in isolate

Comment: instanceof can tell you what class an object belongs to, but it won't do what you're looking for. It's not recommended to use the Object class unless you absolutely need to; it's much better to define your own class which extends Object.